# Alea.CUDA. Migrate from v2 to v3.0

Tags: f#, aleagpu

Is there manual for migration from Alea.CUDA v2 to Alea.CUDA v3?

We use packages Alea.CUDA.Fody and Alea.CUDA.Unbound from Nuget, and next namespaces: Alea.CUDA.Utilities.Array2D, Alea.CUDA, Alea.CUDA.CULib, Alea.CUDA.Utilities, Alea.CUDA.IL.

Now we want to migrate to v3 (because v2 is not available on Nuget). Which packages and which namespaces should we use?